# The multi-part identifier "iis.sourceId" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Any suggstion/ solution for this problem ?

The multi-part identifier "iis.sourceId" could not be bound.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InstrumentSourceSnapSelector] 
    @searchedString nvarchar(100) = null
, @at datetime

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SET @at=dateadd(MILLISECOND, -datepart(MILLISECOND, @at), isnull(@at,getdate()))  --on tronque les ms


CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    SourceId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    instrumentIdentifierId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    instrumentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    vacationId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    MaxReqTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 
    SourceId,
    instrumentIdentifierId, 
    instrumentId, 
    vacationId, 
    max(requestTime) as MaxReqTime 
FROM 
    (instrumentSourceSnap inst
    INNER JOIN 
    VacationTask T 
    ON inst.vacationTaskId = T.id)
GROUP BY 
    SourceId,instrumentIdentifierId, instrumentId, vacationId

SELECT DISTINCT

      iss.id 
    , i.name    AS Name
    , s.name    AS sourceName
    , d.name    AS identifier
    , ii.value  AS identifierValue 
    , v.name    AS Vacation

FROM 
      instrumentSourceSnap iss
      INNER JOIN #TEMP T
        ON 
          T.sourceId = iis.sourceId AND
          T.instrumentIdentifierId = iis.instrumentIdentifierId AND
          T.instrumentId = iis.instrumentId AND
          T.MaxReqTime = iis.ReuqestTime
      INNER JOIN vacationTask vt ON vt.id = iss.vacationTaskId
      INNER JOIN vacation v      ON v.id = vt.vacationId
      INNER JOIN instrument i    ON i.id = iss.instrumentId     
          INNER JOIN source s        ON s.id = iss.sourceId
      INNER JOIN instrumentIdentifier ii ON ii.instrumentId=i.id
      INNER JOIN identifier d ON d.Id=ii.identifierId
          INNER JOIN instrumentSource si ON si.instrumentId = i.id and si.sourceId = s.id


END
GO
```

Comment: Should be `iss`, `iss` is the alias you gave to `instrumentSourceSnap`

Comment: Write `iss.sourceId` instead of `iis.sourceId` (2 S's instead of 2 I's). There are other places where it's badly written also.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the comments said, replaced all `iis` with `iss` as `iss` is the alias for `instrunmentSourceSnap`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InstrumentSourceSnapSelector] 
    @searchedString nvarchar(100) = null
, @at datetime

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SET @at=dateadd(MILLISECOND, -datepart(MILLISECOND, @at), isnull(@at,getdate()))  --on tronque les ms


CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    SourceId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    instrumentIdentifierId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    instrumentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    vacationId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    MaxReqTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 
    SourceId,
    instrumentIdentifierId, 
    instrumentId, 
    vacationId, 
    max(requestTime) as MaxReqTime 
FROM 
    (instrumentSourceSnap inst
    INNER JOIN 
    VacationTask T 
    ON inst.vacationTaskId = T.id)
GROUP BY 
    SourceId,instrumentIdentifierId, instrumentId, vacationId

SELECT DISTINCT

      iss.id 
    , i.name    AS Name
    , s.name    AS sourceName
    , d.name    AS identifier
    , ii.value  AS identifierValue 
    , v.name    AS Vacation

FROM 
      instrumentSourceSnap iss
      INNER JOIN #TEMP T
        ON 
          T.sourceId = iss.sourceId AND
          T.instrumentIdentifierId = iss.instrumentIdentifierId AND
          T.instrumentId = iss.instrumentId AND
          T.MaxReqTime = iss.ReuqestTime
      INNER JOIN vacationTask vt ON vt.id = iss.vacationTaskId
      INNER JOIN vacation v      ON v.id = vt.vacationId
      INNER JOIN instrument i    ON i.id = iss.instrumentId     
          INNER JOIN source s        ON s.id = iss.sourceId
      INNER JOIN instrumentIdentifier ii ON ii.instrumentId=i.id
      INNER JOIN identifier d ON d.Id=ii.identifierId
      INNER JOIN instrumentSource si ON si.instrumentId = i.id and si.sourceId = s.id


END
GO
```